# How to optimize painfully slow SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.  The first 'user' table, consists of rows that record login events from a user.  The table looks something like this:

```
LoginTable
LoginID   Name    Time
100       Joe     12:00pm
101       Bob     3:30pm
102       Joe     4:00pm
103       Sue     6:15pm
```

The second table records additional metrics about each login, tho not common, the number of additional items recorded could change.  The table looks something like this:

```
MetricsTable
MetricID  LoginID   Label       Data
500       100       IPAddress   1.2.3.4
501       100       Attempts    25       
502       100       Status      Good
503       101       IPAddress   1.2.3.5
504       101       Attempts    19       
505       101       Status      Bad
506       102       IPAddress   1.2.3.6
507       102       Attempts    35       
508       102       Status      Hold
509       103       IPAddress   1.2.3.7
510       103       Attempts    4       
511       103       Status      Trial
```

I am trying to build a query of the LoginTable that would for each row, show additional columns representing the extra metrics data associated with each login event.

One solution is to do something like this:

```
SELECT LoginTable.LoginID, LoginTable.Name, LoginTable.Time, 
(SELECT MetricsTable.Data FROM MetricsTable WHERE
 MetricsTable.LoginID=LoginTable.LoginID and 
 MetricsTable.Label="IPAddress") as IPAddressEx
FROM LoginTable
```

That query would show one extra column that shows the 'IPAddress' value recorded for that event.  I could then add 2 more sub queries like that to show additional columns for 'Attempts' and 'Status' (note these are just fake examples).  I am not concerned about being able to automatically identify there are more potential columns, I can add them manually if they come along.  However this technique of adding a sub query for each extra column appears to be painfully slow.

What is a better way to accomplish this?

Please assume that I cannot restructure the tables.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't mention indexes. Do you have any, on which columns, and when were they last rebuilt/reorganized? Are statistics up to date?

Comment: Can you show the explain plan for the query?

Comment: Why can't you simply join the two tables?

Comment: I only call the query painfully slow because anyone can look at it and realize that it will take forever to run.  So my question in reality is not so much about speed, but about how to write it 'better'.  The answers below involving PIVOT are the direction I needed, I was unaware of the PIVOT action.  I am asking the question because I am not a MS SQL expert, my wheelhouse is C, C++, MFC, .NET Winforms, JavaScript... whatever, I can't know everything all the time, that is what SO is for...despite the smarty down vote... grrr.  Going to try the suggestions below then mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a result set like this:

```
LoginID   Name    Time   IP  Attempts  Status FutureColumn1 FutureColumn2 ...
```

You can [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), or [Dynamic PIVOT](http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/using-sql-server-20052008-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns-dynamic-pivot/) your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  LoginID,
        Name,
        Time,
        [IPAddress],
        [Attempts],
        [Status]
From   (Select  LoginTable.LoginID, 
                LoginTable.Name, 
                LoginTable.Time, 
                MetricsTable.Data,
                MetricsTable.Label
        From    LoginTable
        Inner   Join MetricsTable
                ON  MetricsTable.LoginID=LoginTable.LoginID) As nested
Pivot  (Min(Data) For Label In ([IPAddress],[Attempts],[Status])) As PivotTable
```

I didn't have time to test this and I'm not the best with on the fly ad-hoc pivots, but I think this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Andrew's answer, I would instead alias the MetricsTable.

```
SELECT LoginTable.LoginID
    ,LoginTable.Name
    ,LoginTable.Time
    ,IPAddress= IPAddress.Data
    ,Attempts = Attempts.Data
FROM LoginTable
    Left Join MetricsTable As IPAddress
    On IPAddress.LoginID=LoginTable.LoginID 
    And IPAddress.Label="IPAddress"
    Left Join MetricsTable As Attempts
    On Attempts.LoginID=LoginTable.LoginID 
    And Attempts.Label="Attempts"
    -- Other joins for additional stats
```

If you know that certain information, like IPAddress, is always available, then use an `Inner Join` instead of a `Left Join`.

You could [pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data, as suggested by Love2Learn, but I prefer straight-forward joins when possible.

In addition, If LoginID is not a PK on the LoginTable, an index on it will increase read speeds.

Likewise, if you do not have an index on MetricsTable.LoginID, I highly recommend that you do so. [Foreign keys benefit from indexes](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/benefits-indexing-foreign-keys).

With the above query, a helpful index on MetricsTable would be on LoginID and Label (in that order) and maybe include Data so that the database engine can read all data from an index. You should do performance testing to see if the overhead of the index is worthwhile.